# Flexbox - Elements Inside A Flex Item Contained By A Scrollable Container Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I'm attempting to convert one of my websites to flexbox and have come across a problem involving vertical scrolling within a flex container. Firefox seems to render it correctly but Chrome/Safari do not. [Here's a link to the code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRxerr).

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item div {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the box 1 & 2 text are not being correctly rendered inside the flex item. Can anyone explain to me what's going on here and how I might fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a padding of 20px, add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the `.item` rule and it will work as intended.

The reason why it doesn't work now is to many items to fit into the `200px` high `container`, so the `items` simply collapse first, as flex shrink defaults to 1, which means they are allowed to shrink, then, when they can't do that anymore they start to scroll.

If you either make the parent higher or delete some items, you'll see how it behaves proper as is.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item div {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `align-items:center` to get the same

Update css part

```
.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /*Add this */
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /*Add this */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item div {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just add

```
.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Add this */
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: I have to say that this actually doesn't solve the issue properly, as the `item`'s doesn't have a padding of 20px. Check my answer to see why.

Answer (score 2):

To fix it, use vertical aligning for the box div's. I assume it has something to do with collapsing padding. I chose for center alignment, but flex-start and flex-end work also.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.item div {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have difficulties to understand how flex-start and flex-end also would work

Comment: it just puts the "box elements" at the top or bottom instead of at the center

Comment: Ah...now I understood what you meant ... the collapsed items :)

Comment: I have to say that this actually doesn't solve the issue properly, as the `item`'s doesn't have a padding of 20px. Check my answer to see why.